# make another Jquery AJAX call in error case of existing AJAX call

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I have the following code which work fine in case of success and error. But what I want to do is make another ajax call in case of error. to some other URL . what is the correct way of doing it. I tried calling the ajax function again but it resulted in a javascript error

this is the sample of working code.

```
$('#save-walkin').die('vclick').live('vclick', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg();
    $.ajax({
                url: 'http://www.someurl.com',
                method: 'POST',
                data: $('#form-createwalkin').serialize(),
                success: function(){
                    $.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg ();
                    document.location.href = "queue.php";
                },
                error: function(){
                    $.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg ();
                    document.location.href = "queue.php";
                }
            });
    return false;
});
```

Where as what I am trying to do is something like this. but It's not working

```
$('#save-walkin').die('vclick').live('vclick', function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
$.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg();
$.ajax({
            url: 'http://www.someurl.com',
            method: 'POST',
            data: $('#form-createwalkin').serialize(),
            success: function(){
                $.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg ();
                document.location.href = "queue.php";
            },
            error: function(){
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'http://www.someotherurl.com',
                    method: 'POST',
                    data: $('#form-createwalkin').serialize(),
                    success: function(){
                        $.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg ();
                        document.location.href = "queue.php";
                     },
                     error: function(){
                         $.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg ();
                         document.location.href = "queue.php";
                     }
                 }
           });
   return false;
});
```

Comment: what javascript error you are getting?

Comment: Looks like you're missing the closing parenthesis from the inner `$.ajax()` call.

Comment: This logic should work, try to put the second call in a function and call that function from error function

Comment: yea it worked. it was just the wrong formation of parenthesis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just not formed correctly. It should look like this:

```
$('#save-walkin').die('vclick').live('vclick', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg();
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://www.someurl.com',
        method: 'POST',
        data: $('#form-createwalkin').serialize(),
        success: function(){
            $.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg ();
            document.location.href = "queue.php";
        },
        error: function(){
            $.ajax({
                url: 'http://www.someotherurl.com',
                method: 'POST',
                data: $('#form-createwalkin').serialize(),
                success: function(){
                    $.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg ();
                    document.location.href = "queue.php";
                },
                error: function(){
                    $.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg ();
                    document.location.href = "queue.php";
                }
            });
        }
    });

    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Deferred objects, those are objects to manipulate async calls, you can solve :

```
$.when($.ajax("/page1.php"), $.ajax("/page2.php"))
  .then(myFunc, myFailure);
```

This way myFunc executes after the 2 ajax calls are made, and myFailure if either one has an error.

You can read more about it in the jquery official documentation:[`JQuery Deferred Object`](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this, storing the Ajax in an object gives you a lot more flexibility, and in the error (fail) function, just call the function again with a different URL.

Will probably need some adjusting, and a counter if it's only suppose to repeat once!

```
runAjax('http://www.someurl.com');

funcion runAjax(url) {
    var jqXHR = $.ajax({
        url: url,
        method: 'POST',
        data: $('#form-createwalkin').serialize()
    });
}

jqXHR.done(function() {
    $.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg ();
    document.location.href = "queue.php";
}.fail(function() {
    runAjax('http://www.someotherurl.com');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think first you have to check your callback,, or error what you are getting..

may be it will help you..

```
$.ajax({
  statusCode: {
    404: function() {
      alert('page not found');
    }
  }
});
```

you can also try to give

```
var menuId = $("ul.nav").first().attr("id");
var request = $.ajax({
  url: "script.php",
  type: "POST",
  data: {id : menuId},
  dataType: "html"
});

request.done(function(msg) {
  $("#log").html( msg );
});

request.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
  alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
});
```